# Phaser3 launch game with parameter

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

I need to launch the phaser game with some input data such as: user, authorization token,score etc. How can I proceed. thx

I didn't figure out how to do it

this is my index.js

```js
import Phaser
import BootScene from './scenes/boot'
import PreloadScene from './scenes/preload'
import GameScene from './scenes/game'
import GameScalePlugin from 'phaser-plugin-game-scale'
import {config} from './config'

let phaserConfig = config.phaser
phaserConfig.type = Phaser.AUTO
//phaserConfig.scene = [PreloadScene, GameScene]
phaserConfig.plugins = {
global: [{
    key: 'GameScalePlugin',
    plugin: GameScalePlugin,
    mapping: 'gameScale',
    data: {
        debounce: false,
        debounceDelay: 50,   // Debounce interval, in ms
        maxHeight: Infinity,
        maxWidth: Infinity,
        minHeight: config.size.minHeight,
        minWidth: config.size.minWidth,
        mode: 'fit',
        resizeCameras: false, // Resize each scene camera when resizing the game
        snap: null, 
       }
    }]
   }
   phaserConfig.banner = { hidePhaser: true }
   let game = new Phaser.Game(phaserConfig)
   game.scene.add('BootScene', BootScene, true, {user:'test', auth:'test-auth'});
   game.scene.add('PreloadScene', PreloadScene);
   game.scene.add('GameScene', GameScene);
```

and this my boot.js

```
import { Scene } from 'phaser'
export default class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
constructor() { super({ key: 'Boot' }) }

    preload() {
        this.load.image('logo', './assets/logo.png')
    }

    init(...params){
        console.info('INIT', params)
    }

    create(...params){   
        this.scene.start('Preload')
    }
}
```

But in the boot it receives an empty object. is a problem within my config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways a easy one is simply using the `init` function of the scene. By starting the scene with the function `add` on the `SceneManager` you can pass parameters to the scene.
*([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scenes.SceneManager.html#add__anchor))*

**Here a short demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 18,
    backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
    banner: false,
}; 

class TestScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
      super('TestScene')
    }
    init(...params){
        console.info('INIT', JSON.stringify(params))
    }
    create (...params){
        console.info('CREATE', JSON.stringify(params))
    }
}

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);

game.scene.add('TestScene', TestScene, true, {user:'test', auth:'test-auth'});

setTimeout( () => {
    console.info(' second Game, with not matching keys');
    
    let game2 = new Phaser.Game(config);

    game2.scene.add('NotMatching', TestScene, true, {user:'test', auth:'test-auth'});
}, 10);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

> ***Info:** the passed parameters will be passed to the `init` and the `create` function, of the started scene. I personally try to always use `init` when possible.*

Comment: I updated my question with the index and boot file

Comment: You didn't aska a question, but I assume you want to knwo Why it doesn't work. The _keys_ have to match. set the key in the constructor to "BootScene". I will update may answer to show the problem.